# Groups' permission from gsuite API Json error "Error cannot be deserialized" Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net, google-workspace, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to retrieve permissions for my groups.

I followed the [article](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/get):  ([GET](https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/groupUniqueId)) and converted it to `vb.net`

```
Dim GrpListReq As New Google.Apis.Groupssettings.v1.GroupsResource.GetRequest(service, strEmail)
Dim first = GrpListReq.Execute.Email
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> "An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized."

Inner exception gives:

> "Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Meaning that the first character is not correct, your JSON should start with {

Comment: @CruleD How to cater for that through the vb .net code?

Comment: You should be getting JSON in proper format, you shouldn't need to fix it yourself. but if you have to you can simply add it yourself manually with string1= "{" & string1